# E ink ebook reader for PDF with Wi-Fi synchronization

Tags: wifi, e-reader, e-ink

I'm looking for a large (with 8 inches screen) ebook reader that will be used to read PDF documents. Additionally it should support storage synchronization via Wi-Fi using some generic method, not tied to its manufacturers online service (like Send-to-PocketBook service). E.g. it could support upload via SSH or FTP, or be able to setup and use some synchronization software like Syncthing.

So requirements are:

1. E Ink 8 inches screen.
2. Support for PDF documents.
3. Storage synchronization via Wi-Fi using some open source software.

Answer (score 1):

Some Kobo ereaders can display PDF docs and [support WiFi](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=248323), and [with some software installation it might be possible to transfer files from your own server](http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=268489),but my experience has been that connection *via* USB to a PC running Calibre is the easiest and most reliable way to transfer files.